# Passing value to script in gsp from drop down menu

Tags: javascript, grails, drop-down-menu, controller, gsp

I'm currently trying to pass the value that is selected from a `g:select` drop down menu and pass it to a script that's inside the same gsp as the drop down menu. For some reason the call to run my script only works when I call the function itself and don't pass a value to it from my controllers function, which is obtaining the value I need to have passed to the script. I'm pretty sure the issue is coming from the point where I pass the value from my controller to my gsp so that it can then be sent to my script but I'm not sure why it's not working when it's passed.

This is the code for my script:

```
function locationParameterSet(data){
    alert("This worked " + data);
}
```

This is the code for my `g:select` drop down menu:

```
<g:select name="locationSelection" from="${location_names}" value="${params.site_id}"
    optionKey="location_id" optionValue="short_name" noSelection="['': '----Site----']"
    onchange="${remoteFunction(controller: 'term', action: 'locationParameterSet',
    onComplete: 'locationParameterSet(data)', params: '\'location_id=\' + this.value',
    options: '[asynchronous: false]')}"/>
```

This is the method that runs when an option is selected from the drop down menu. It passes the `id` back to the `g:select` and `onComplete: 'locationParameterSet(data)'` is ran once the method inside the controller finishes. The `onComplete` calls my script function `locationParameterSet(data)`:

```
def locationParameterSet = {
    session["location_id"] = params.location_id
    def location_id = params.location_id
    [location_id: location_id]
}
```

Is there a different way to send the `id` to the gsp so that my script will run?

Answer (score 0):

one thing i don´t understand on your question is :

why do you want to send the id again to gsp ? you already have it in your select.

if the onchange handler works it should be as easy as :

```
<g:select name="locationSelection" from="${location_names}" value="${params.site_id}"
    optionKey="location_id" optionValue="short_name" noSelection="['': '----Site----']"
    onchange="locationParameterSet(this.value)"/>
```

Somehow the onchange is not included in the /latest/docs of grails select, even i remember i saw it there, but anyway its not a grails feature its just a javascript event.
It should be the same like writing :

```
   var sel = document.getElementById('giveSelectAnId');
   sel.onchange = function() {
      locationParameterSet(this.value)
   }
```